# Why does celery on_worker_shutdown not maintain object state

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to accumulate a list of events in memory and then write them to an API periodically in a celery task. I want to attempt to flush the buffer if the celery worker is being shut down, so I attempted to use `on_worker_shutdown.connect` with my flush function. However, although it does call the flush function, it shows that there are no items in my buffer.

My code is as follows (simplified a little):

```py
from celery import Task, Celery
from celery.signal import worker_shutdown


class EventsBuffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = []
        worker_shutdown.connect(self._on_worker_shutdown)

    def add_event(self, event):
        self.buffer.append(event)
        if len(self.buffer) > 50:
            self.flush()

    def flush():
        print('Flushing the buffer with %s items' % len(self.buffer))
        # do actual flush work

    def _on_worker_shutdown(self, **kwargs):
        print('Shutting down')
        self.flush()

class TaskBase(Task):
   def __init__(self):
      self.events_buffer = EventsBuffer()

app = Celery(__name__)

@app.task(base=TaskBase, bind=True)
def send_event(self, event):
   self.events_buffer.add_event(event)
```

Let's say I add two tasks then try to shut it down.

Expected result is:

```
Shutting down.
Flushing the buffer with 2 items.
```

However in reality I get:

```
Shutting down.
Flushing the buffer with 0 items.
```

And upon inspection, the buffer object is empty.

What's going on, and how can I accomplish what I want to do?